# How Can I delete other duplicate values of same date by keeping last data in Laravel and mySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

**What I Have :**

I have an *'items'* table on Item Model where data are like -

```
id----item_id-----name------created_at
1-----1234------test1------2021-07-05 06:44:48
2-----1234------test1------2021-07-05 06:48:34
3-----1234------test1------2021-07-05 06:50:09
4-----1234------test1------2021-07-06 09:40:16
5-----1234------test1------2021-07-06 06:12:13
6-----1234------test1------2021-07-06 05:41:43
```

**What I Want :**

I want to delete duplicate data of same-day just keeping latest one.

```
id----item_id-----name------created_at
3-----1234------test1------2021-07-05 06:50:09
4-----1234------test1------2021-07-06 09:40:16
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the below query, here I am selecting the latest  `timestamp` from the table, in your case it is the created_date

```
SELECT T1.* FROM TABLE_NAME T1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT   MAX(CREATED_DATE) CREATED_DATE
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    GROUP BY   DATE_FORMAT(CREATED_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d' )
) T2 ON T1.CREATED_DATE = T2.CREATED_DATE ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want id/date combinations where there is only one row.  If so, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.item_id = t.item_id and
                        date(t2.created_at) = date(t.created_at) and
                        t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

An alternative uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by item_id, date(created_at)) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```